# Problema com tamanho da div ao rolar a página

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Bom desenvolvi um efeito que diminui a altura da minha `div` quando dou um scroll na página porem quando eu utilizo o `scroll` o efeito ocorre normalmente mais quando eu subo a página a `div` não volta ao normal gostaria de saber porque segue o o código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[![

```js
var scrollTimer = null;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var top = $(document).scrollTop();
  clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
  scrollTimer = setTimeout(
    function() {
      console.log(top);
      if (top == 1500) {
        $(".spaces-box").animate({
          height: '280px'
        });
        $(".description-events-box").animate({
          padding: '130px 0'
        });
      } else {
        $(".spaces-box").animate({
          height: '100px'
        });
        $(".description-events-box").animate({
          padding: '60px 0'
        });
      }
    }, 200);

});
```

```css
.spaces-box {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 280px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.spaces-box .description-events-box {
  padding-top: 130px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.spaces-box .-bg1 {
  background-color: #333;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

.spaces-box .-bg1:hover {
  background-color: #ff283b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spaces-box">
  <div class="work -bg1" id="p1">
    <i class="icon -workshop"></i>
    <p class="description-events-box workshop">Workshops</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Ibl.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Ibl.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa

```
//$(window).scrollTop() == 0 || 0 == false
if(!$(window).scrollTop())
```

ao invés de

```
if(top == 1500)
```

Se ele estiver no topo da página a `div` volta ao normal

```js
var scrollTimer = null;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var top = $(document).scrollTop();
  clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
  scrollTimer = setTimeout(
    function() {
      //console.log(top);
      if (!$(window).scrollTop()) {
        $(".spaces-box").animate({
          height: '280px'
        });
        $(".description-events-box").animate({
          padding: '130px 0'
        });
      } else {
        $(".spaces-box").animate({
          height: '100px'
        });
        $(".description-events-box").animate({
          padding: '60px 0'
        });
      }
    }, 200);

});
```

```css
.spaces-box {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 280px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.spaces-box .description-events-box {
  padding-top: 130px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.spaces-box .-bg1 {
  background-color: #333;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

.spaces-box .-bg1:hover {
  background-color: #ff283b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spaces-box">
  <div class="work -bg1" id="p1">
    <i class="icon -workshop"></i>
    <p class="description-events-box workshop">Workshops</p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
<p>texto de teste</p>
```

Comment: Cara vlw pela resposta mais me tira uma utra dúvida se eu quise-se  que esse efeito acontece-se em um determinado ponto na pagina sem ser no top quando o scroll for = 0 tem como ? tipo rolar a pagina em 350px apartir disso o efeito ativa e quando for menor que esses 350px ele volta ao normal

Comment: @Kirito se entendi o que tu quer, tem sim, justamente com o método que usei no if, o scrollTop(); tu pode armazenar a posição, por exemplo: var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); e a partir dai tu faz o que quiser, if(scroll>350) //volta ao normal... talvez não ficou claro pra ti que o scrollTop() serve também para pegar a posição da barra de rolagem.